# Airflow Pool DAGs queue pattern

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

i'd like to know if exists any kind of documentation regarding pool slots queue pattern ( for ie. FIFO, LIFO ... ). Unlike what is specified by other services like AWS SQS for example, the official documentation here ( https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/pools.html ) talking in a general way of a pool, but if i have multiple resources that push DAGs into same pool what is the pop pattern of the DAG that need to be executed ?
Any document or starting point about this topic will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance